# Problem with ASP.NET MVC 2 Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following URL:

http://localhost/PagingController/ShowPage?pageNumber=3

When user clicks this link he must be redirected to the following URL:

http://localhost/**MyController**/ **MyAction**?pageNumber=3

How can I create a mapping rule for these URLs? I don't understand how to get **pageNumber** parameter with URL templates such as .../{controller}/{action}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to define a route for it. If you use querystring, you can just get it in the action like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int pageNumber)
```